# clearing a textbox which is in a function

Tags: powershell

i have a function that create a textbox (info box) and can be called from other functions or from buttons.

```
function InfoBox ($x,$y,$text){
    $TextboxInfoBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $TextboxInfoBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($x,$y)
    $TextboxInfoBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,800)
#   Readonly Textbox.
    $TextboxInfoBox.Enabled = $true
    $TextboxInfoBox.Text = $text
    $TabPanelButtons.Controls.Add($TextboxInfoBox)
}
```

After i called the textbox once, i am not able to overwrite it with another info message.
the first time i call with all the parameters ($x, $y & $text).

```
Infobox -x '100' -y '150' -text 'This is the first message'
```

The second time i only want to give another text. How can i clear the textbox and give only a new text like:

```
Infobox -text "This is the second message"
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: The function should return the textbox after the creation. So you could use it later and overwrite the text property.

Comment: u mean i have to add $textboxinfobox at the end of the function?

Comment: yes `return  $textboxinfobox`.

Comment: @guiwhatsthat The `return` statement is not needed, `$TextboxInfoBox` on its own line is enough, see my answer.

Comment: @zett42 yes indeed it is not needed, but makes the code looks cleaner and better readable IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commenter wrote, the function has to output the TextBox object so you can reference it later to change the text:

```
function InfoBox ($x,$y,$text){
    $TextboxInfoBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $TextboxInfoBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($x,$y)
    $TextboxInfoBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,800)
#   Readonly Textbox.
    $TextboxInfoBox.Enabled = $true
    $TextboxInfoBox.Text = $text
    $TabPanelButtons.Controls.Add($TextboxInfoBox)

    $TextboxInfoBox  # Output
}
```

Contrary to most other programming languages, in PowerShell you normally don't need to use the [`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return?view=powershell-7.2) statement, except for early return from a function. Simply referring to a variable by name on its own line will output its value from the function.

Now you can store the output in a variable and change the text:

```
$box = Infobox -x 100 -y 150 -text 'This is the first message'

$box.Text = 'This is the second message'
```